# Textbox "Method or data member not found"

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing an aircraft system emulation using Excel (2013) VBA, Windows 10. I have macros which will allow students to operate the system and display it on the screen. Before the xmas break i was doing some  development work and it was working fine. However I have come back to it today I am getting a "Method or data member not found" for some of the textboxes, which are still showing the correct names. I would say that in design mode I can't access the textbox properties.

This is the code that was working:

```
Sub Batt_MasterOFFExample()

    ' Indications
    Sheet2.Ess1Volt.Text = "---V"
    With Sheet2.Ess1Volt
        .ForeColor = &HFFFFFF
    End With

End Sub
```

Now when I run it it highlights `Sheet2.Ess1Volt.Text = "---V"` and gives me the error.

Comment: is `Sheet2` suppose to be your worksheet's name ? or the index ?

Comment: Please update your question to clarify what `Ess1Volt` refers to. We guess that `Sheet2` refers to `Worksheets("Sheet2")` but no-one has any idea what your `Ess1Volt` is.

Comment: "Ess1Volt" is the name of the text box. It displays the Essential Bus 1 Voltage. Part of the DC electrical circuit i'm animating. I have 2 sheets in the workbook. Sheet 1 displays the electrical wiring diagram, with switches that you can turn on/off. Sheet 2 is the Graphic Display that would be visible to the pilot. I'll have the circuit up on the whiteboard and the cockpit display on my laptop. I've animated a few other systems fire protection, brakes etc, but the DC electrical system is much more complicated!

Answer (score 0):

use option explicit to avoid such mistakes. ;-)

Sheet2 isn't declared as a worksheet (dim Sheet2 as worksheet  //  set sheet2= whatever ) , so I assume you meant Worksheets("Sheet2")

Comment: You can definitely do `SheetX.Range("A1").Value = "foo"` or whatever - if `SheetX` is the name of the sheet object. You can check that in the Properties window in the VBE by selecting a sheet in the Project pane. Agree, as always, about using `Option Explicit`

Comment: Yes, and same goes with Ess1Volt, wtf is that? Option explicit FTW!

Comment: "Ess1Volt" is the name of the text box. It displays the Essential Bus 1 Voltage. Part of the DC electrical circuit i'm animating.

Comment: I've found out what the problem is. All the textboxes that were on the worksheet have converted to objects. How I did that I do not know. If I place a 'new' textbox on the sheet and rewrite the code from 'Ess1volt' to textbox1 it works. Anyone got an idea what i did? is there a way of converting them back?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. After deleting the textbox and recreating it, everything worked just fine.